# User Customizable Segmented Control Default

Tags: iphone, xcode, default, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm making a tab bar based app and in one of the tabs I have a segmented control. I wanted to make another tab for more options, and in that tab an option for settings. In that settings option I wanted to make something where you could choose the default segment to show up when you go to that tab with the segmented control in it. Unfortunately I am a coding beginner and have no idea how to make this happen. I've looked for tutorials on how to do this, but I couldn't find any. I hope someone can help me through this completely. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complicated task and if you are a beginner it might not make too much sense. You might need to spend some more time and get comfortable with iPhone development a little more to grasp all of this... but here ya go:

There are many ways to do this, this is just one, but it should work.

On your settings tab, you can create an IBAction method, something like:

```
-(IBAction) changedSegmentedControlDefault:(id)sender
```

In the xib for your settings tab, I would probably put another segmented control with the same options as the other tab and whatever choice the user makes on the settings tab becomes the default for the other tab. Connect the Value Changed event on that settings control to the changedSegmentedControlDefault method so that whenever a user change that control it will call your method.

In that method, I would either save the selectedIndex from the control for later use either using CoreData or a Settings bundle. These are huge topics all on their own, so its too much to go into here. Whichever way you save that information for later use.... just save it every time they change.

Then on the original tab... in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller for that tab, look up that saved value from CoreData or your Settings bundle and use that selectedIndex to set the starting value on your segmented control. Something like:

```
self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = savedDefaultIndex;
```

Again, there are a hundred different ways you could do this and it is a fairly complicated task which involves many different things to learn. I hope this helps you move in the right direction though.